# create another column with 1 and 0 using np.where, on a series of multiple values

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, series

Hi I am trying to create a column. 
where ever column ChannelID is 'J','F','H' then column name indirect should be 1 else 0, i believe there are spaces in my csv file in each cell of ChannelID columns.

## original Data

```
cd          Channel month
B               J   1
B               J   3
B               M   5
B               J   7
B               J   9
B               H   2
B               J   5
B               J   6
B               J   1
B               J   7
```

## expected data set

```
cd         Channel  month   Indirect
B               J   1   1
B               J   3   1
B               M   5   0
B               J   7   1
B               J   9   1
B               H   2   1
B               J   5   1
B               J   6   1
B               C   1   0
B               J   7   1
```

## code used

```
Output['Indirect']=np.where((Output['Channel']=='J')|(Output['Channel']=='H'),1,0)
```

but this code gives only 0 in indirect column and if i use below code then i get error-

```
if Output['Channel']== ('J' or 'F' or 'H' or 'G' or 'I'or 'K' or 'M'):
    Output['Indirect'] = 1
else:
    Output['Indirect'] = 0
```

error-  ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

As there is space after value in each cell in Channel column then i used strip to remove it then i get below error-

```
if Output['Channel'].strip()== ('J' or 'F' or 'H' or 'G' or 'I'or 'K' or 'M'):
    Output['Indirect'] = 1
else:
    Output['Indirect'] = 0
```

error- AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strip'

Many thanks in advance ,

also i have attached the screen shot of space in each cell [image: space after j and all values in all cells]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a list to [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and cast the boolean type using [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas.Series.astype):

```
In [4]:
df['indirect'] = df['Channel'].str.strip().isin(['J','F','H']).astype(int)
df

Out[4]:
  cd Channel  month  indirect
0  B       J      1         1
1  B       J      3         1
2  B       M      5         0
3  B       J      7         1
4  B       J      9         1
5  B       H      2         1
6  B       J      5         1
7  B       J      6         1
8  B       J      1         1
9  B       J      7         1
```

Here is the boolean series generated from `isin`:

```
In [5]:
df['Channel'].str.strip().isin(['J','F','H'])

Out[5]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
9     True
Name: Channel, dtype: bool
```

If needed you can pre-process the data using the vectorised `str.strip`, `str.upper` to strip white spaces and uppercase the strings.

Comment: If there is a space characters in the data you can use `df['Channel'].str.strip().isin(['J','F','H'])`

Comment: That's true, additionally one could do `.str.upper` also to be extra safe

Comment: df['Channel'].str.strip().isin(['J','F','H'])  gives True and False instead of 1 and 0

Comment: @SanchitAluna `.astype(int)`

Comment: @SanchitAluna did you see the output from the upper half of my answer?

Comment: @RomainX. nice catch. OP's original code should work once they strip white space.

Comment: @ EdChum  yes i saw the output, it works fantastic thanks a ton